# Как в sympy задать сразу несколько уравнений?

Tags: python, sympy

Задаю в sympy несколько уровнений, но почему то он не может найти другие решения этих уравнений
Вот код:

```
x = sym.Symbol('x')
y = sym.Symbol('y')
p = sym.Symbol('p')
q = sym.Symbol('q')


answer = sym.nsolve((calc12Plus, calc12minus, calc14minus, calc14plus), (x, y, p, q), -1)
print(answer)
```

Если пробую через solve, то пишет:

```
TypeError: Can't multiply sequence by non-integer of type '<class 'sympy.core.numbers.ImaginaryUnit'>'
```

А ошибку пишет:

```
TypeError: _lambdifygenerated() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'y', 'p', and 'q'
```

```
q1 = x + y + 2 * p - q - 9
q2 = x + y - 2 * p + q - 7
q3 = x - y + p + 2 * q + 9
q4 = x - y - p - 2 * q - 5

answer = sym.nsolve((q1, q2, q3, q4), (x, y, p, q), -1)
print(answer)
```

Даже когда делаю простой пример ошибка остается(

Comment: `не может найти другие решения этих уравнений` - а не другое это какое? Добавьте сами уравнения в вопрос, а также что вы получаете при решении, и что ожидаете получить.

Comment: @insolor, Добавил пример.

Comment: Под `q1 = x + y + 2 * p - q - 9` подразумевается уравнение `x + y + 2 * p - q - 9 == 0`?